# Parsing Friendly Routed URL Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I have links in a ListView going to a detailed page view (not MVC):

```
http://localhost/mysite/events.aspx?eventID=14
```

After implementing routing, the link is in the form:

```
http://localhost/mysite/Events/14
```

What's the best way to parse/obtain the eventID value in the Events.aspx code-behind and how should/would I check to make sure that a value was actually passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and am leaving the question up for others to refer to:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if (Page.RouteData.Values["EventID"] != null)
    {
        int eventID = Convert.ToInt32(Page.RouteData.Values["EventID"]);
    }
}
```